# Does the variable maker work only with latin letters and numbers?

Tags: macros, variable

How can I make the variable for non-Latex user, for example, using the `\newcommand{}{}` with parameters?
For example, I want the user change only the word in newcommand description and it will change in whole document automatically?

```
\newcommand{\R}{My system}
...
\section{Introduction}
Here I would like to introduce \( \R \)
...
   \begin{table}[]
       \centering
       \begin{tabular}{c|c}
           \( \R \) &  \\
                    & 
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Caption}
       \label{tab:my_label}
   \end{table}
```

This doesn't work with Russian letters (`\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}` and `\selectlanguage{russian}` is added and in usage)

Ok, posting the full example where I don't get anything (blank space instead of russian word):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{ICD}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}   %для таблиц со слиянием столбцов и строк
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}      %для таблиц с заданной шириной столбца
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
%\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{3cm}}
%\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{DB5800}

\ProcessOptions

\begin{document}
%\hoffset = 20pt
%\maketitle
\selectlanguage{russian}


\tableofcontents


\newcommand{\Mysyst}{ \begin{center} \selectlanguage{russian} система \end{center}}

 \section{Introduction}
    Here I would like to introduce \( \Mysyst \)
    ...
       \begin{table}[]
           \centering
           \begin{tabular}{c|c}
               \( \Mysyst \) &  \\
                        & 
           \end{tabular}
           \caption{Caption}
           \label{tab:my_label}
       \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you want to add the non-ASCII characters? In the name of the macro, it's impossible with standard `pdflatex` (maybe in LuaLaTeX). In the content, there is no problem. Can you post a *full* example showing the problem? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes

Comment: BTW. in your example `\R` expands to `My system` and then it's used in math mode --- which clearly ins't. Are you sure you really do not want *italics*?

Comment: Still: this is not an example. Put a code that I can copy, paste to my editor, and run compile. Like my code in the answer. (and btw, it's better if you prepare your MWE and post another answer). Please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that answers: it will take a bit of time, but you'll gain it back in no time

Comment: @Rmano oh, thank you! reading it. I just deleted the files that I input in my code. Gonna improve and make MWE. But I think something wrong with cyrillic libraries usage in my code, because it says that "\cyrs invalid in math mode" . Studying all this. And many thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can't use cyrillic characters in math mode. Again, are you sure you need math mode? That is for math formulas, nothing else. If you prepare an example that fails, and explains what you are trying to obtain, you'll have an answer. Notice that in my code, trying to put `ñ` in a math formula will also fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### New answer after the MWE

1. You are using `\(` and `\)` delimiter here --- they enter mathematical mode. I do not read russian, but I think that  система is not a formula, isn't it? If you want to typeset it in italic or slanted) font, use `\textit` (or `\emph`, or `\textsl`, depending on the objective). In math mode you can have just formulas: https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10
2. I do not get what you want to obtain with the `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}` there. In the tabular, the text is already centered. And there is no sense in "centering" *inside* a paragraph, like you are trying to do in the first line of text.
3. `\ProcessOptions` is for package creators, not user, avoid it. And you have to specify where you want your floating, so I added `[ht]` (you should have had a warning).

Correct those and you have:

[image: output of the corrected MWE]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}   %для таблиц со слиянием столбцов и строк
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}      %для таблиц с заданной шириной столбца
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}


\tableofcontents

% Additional braces to confine the effect of selectlanguage
\newcommand{\Mysyst}{{\selectlanguage{russian} система}}

 \section{Introduction}
    Here I would like to introduce \emph{\Mysyst}
    ...
       \begin{table}[ht]
           \centering
           \begin{tabular}{c|c}
               \Mysyst &  \\
                        & 
           \end{tabular}
           \caption{Caption}
           \label{tab:my_label}
       \end{table}

\end{document}
```

#### Original answer

Just to show you why an MWE is really necessary in LaTeX to understand the problem: this snippet:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}
\newcommand{\R}{The letter ``ñ''} 
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Here I would like to introduce \emph{\R}

   \begin{table}
       \centering
       \begin{tabular}{c|c}
           \emph{\R} &  \\
                    & 
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Caption}
       \label{tab:my_label}
   \end{table}

\end{document}
```

works perfectly, giving

[image: output from the above snippet]

...so we are at a loss to say where your problem *really* is.

Comment: Yeah, sure i'm lost too... For example, this code inputs the russian word : \newcommand{\FirstBlock}{ \begin{center} \selectlanguage{russian} система \end{center}}

Comment: Just prepare a simple MWE like mine showing your problem, instead of posting non-compilable snippet, and somebody will find the issue! (And chances are that, while creating the MWE, you'll find the error by yourself. It happens to me all the time)

Comment: ...and you *can't* use `\begin{center}....\end{center}` in a tabular `c` column, or `\emph`... this is creating paragraphs. If you put this in your example, together with the error text, the community can help. Otherwise, it's a game of guessing

Comment: yeah, I followed your advice and I know that I do stupid things using \begin{center} but it works in some kind. I'm really lost at this point right now. Will read more about making the \newcommand. I just need the variable where I can place the string text. Anyway, thank you for help I appreciate your support

Comment: I would suggest going throu https://www.learnlatex.org/ --- it's worth the while, and it will clarify some concepts that will help you a better experience with LaTeX

Comment: thanks a lot, learnlatex.org even has free lessons and fast compiler with text processor! Actually the mathematical mode was the reason of getting nothing when I used  \( and \) . Furthermore I\ve deleted the \begin{center}...\end{center} following your advice. I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134846/discussion-between-programmer1988-and-rmano).